# Using SendGrid and B2C Custom Policy to send customised email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Am trying to combine azure b2c and sendgrid to send a custom verification code email using SendGrid.

after performing the steps mention the reference link below, am getting an error saying

> Basic credentials specified for 'SendOtp' are invalid. Check that the credentials are correct and that access has been granted by the resource.

reference link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid

Stuck for entire day. any help would be appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly the answer to this situation, but other times when I had the same message, it was exactly what the error said - wrong creds (username/password/token)

Answer (score 0):

### Azure SendGrid setup incorrect

Azure requires you to setup the SaaS solution called "Twilio SendGrid".
Did you follow the [guide](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021#create-a-twilio-sendgrid-accountcreate-a-twilio-sendgrid-account) and did you set this up correctly?
Azure creates a SendGrid account from the portal itself, and only when that is configured correctly, it'll make a valid connection.

### Wrong permissions on API key

Also make sure your SendGrid API key has the correct permissions to execute the actions you wish.

### Not defining policy key

Last but not least, make sure the your policy key with the SendGrid API key is defined in the Identity Experience Framework, near your custom policies.